# H2 ADA Violation

Tags: html

I am getting [H2 violation](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H2) for below anchor tags.
It says 'H2: Combining adjacent image and text links for the same resource'

```
<div class="selected-label ccyImage">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title=""  class="btn selectedOption"></a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn dropdown-html-toggle" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

But there is no any image used. Not getting how to resolve it.

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0)"` is incredibly "*old school*", and as far as I know also violates Content Security Policy in a page nowadays. Any JavaScript functionality should be entirely separate from the HTML. If something is a button, use a button element goddammit, and make sure it has some real text, not rely on CSS background images for what the button does :D

Answer (score 0):

So you have some unspecified tool which is detecting an accessibility problem which is different to the accessibility problem you actually have (or it is being really smart and noticing that you are expressing content using *background* images … don't do that).

There's not much you can do about the misidentification of the problem other than to report a bug to whomever makes the tool.

You can make your HTML more accessible by:

1. Not using links when you aren't linking somewhere. If you're using `href="javascript:void(0);"` then you're doing something wrong.

   - Link to somewhere useful and [progressively enhance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) *or*
   - Use a button (not a link) if you can't make it work without JS
2. Putting content in your links (or buttons). There is no text at all there to give any clue to the user what the interactive element is going to do.